# Python newbie: trying to create a script that opens a file and replaces words

Tags: python, file-manipulation

im trying to create a script that opens a file and replace every 'hola' with 'hello'.

```
f=open("kk.txt","w")

for line in f:
  if "hola" in line:
      line=line.replace('hola','hello')

f.close()
```

But im getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "prueba.py", line 3, in 
>       for line in f: IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: Why did you open the file with "w" mode?  What tutorial are you using to learn Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're opening the file for writing first. When you open a file for writing, *the contents of the file are deleted*, which makes it quite difficult to do replacements! If you want to replace words in the file, you have a three-step process:

1. Read the file into a string
2. Make replacements in that string
3. Write that string to the file

In code:

```
# open for reading first since we need to get the text out
f = open('kk.txt','r')
# step 1
data = f.read()
# step 2
data = data.replace("hola", "hello")
f.close()
# *now* open for writing
f = open('kk.txt', 'w')
# step 3
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: We should teach beginners to use 'with' from the start - see Max Shawabkeh's answer.

Comment: @paul I don't disagree; however, since the user was already having difficulty with the concept of manipulating files, I originally decided to keep my answer as close to his original code as possible. Since a subsequent question by the user indicated Python 2.5 (which requires a special import from the `__future__`), I figured I might as well not change it. The other answer is, of course, equally correct if not as explicit.

Comment: And beware that simple replace will a) not match "Hola" and give "Hello", and b) *will* match 'hola' in 'scholar' giving 'schellor'.

Answer (score 7):

```
open('test.txt', 'w').write(open('test.txt', 'r').read().replace('hola', 'hello'))
```

Or if you want to properly close the file:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as src:
    src_text = src.read()

with open('test.txt', 'w') as dst:
    dst.write(src_text.replace('hola', 'hello'))
```

Comment: True, but for a beginner, this is the most simple and straightforward way.

Comment: Answer shadows 'input' built-in, maybe src_text might be a better variable name?

Comment: @Paul: Might as well. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You've opened the file for writing, but you're reading from it. Open the original file for reading and a new file for writing. After the replacement, rename the original out and the new one in.

Answer (score 3):

You could also have a look at the [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement.